# If Condition met then Vlookup if not then vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

In my sheet I have:

C5 in my current sheet is 1, the logic is if 1 is in column C in current sheet then bring me the value column 12 in target sheet, if not 1/or if false in current sheet then bring me column 11.

When i do a regular vlookup, `=VLOOKUP('current sheet'!B5,target sheet!A:L,12,FALSE)` , i get the correct value(2500). I am not using the if logic in this one though.

Getting wrong value here , 2350 which is column 11 but I want col 12, which is 2500.

```
=IF(C5="1",VLOOKUP('current sheet'!B5,target sheet!A:L,12,FALSE),VLOOKUP('current sheet'!B5,target sheet!A:L,11,FALSE))/1000000
```

Comment: `VLOOKUP('current sheet'!B5....` what is `'current sheet'!B5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"1"` does not Equal `1`.  One is a text string and the other is a number.  If the `1` in C5 is stored as a number use `C5= 1` not `C5 = "1"`

```
=IF(C5=1,VLOOKUP('current sheet'!B5,target sheet!A:L,12,FALSE),VLOOKUP('current sheet'!B5,target sheet!A:L,11,FALSE))/1000000
```